# Android Folder Layout

Tags: home-screen-folders

I just installed the 8.0 update, and don't like how they changed the layout of my folders. Before installing this update, the size of my folders would be 3x3 rows, and now they changed it to 4x4 rows. Is there a setting or anything I can do to change it back to the layout that I had before?

Comment: What device do you have?

Comment: I have a Samsung Galaxy S7 Edge

Answer (score 0):

On the S7 you can go to your home screen and go into edit mode by long pressing on an empty area or pinching on your home screen. Then click screen grid and choose the size you want. Unfortunately it seems the 3x3 option you say it had was removed.
[Source](https://gadgetguideonline.com/s7/galaxy-s7-online-manual/how-to-use-galaxy-s7-screen-grid-to-customize-app-icon-size-in-home-screen-and-apps-screen/)

Another option is you can download a custom launcher from the Play Store and use it instead. Your mileage will vary with those however.

Comment: Sorry, that didn't do it. Anything else I can try?

Comment: @Lene editied my answer with a more likely solution.